# app service why public ip nat gateway is used instead of private ip

Tags: azure, integration, azure-appservice, vnet

i have an issue about app service with vnet intégration and nat gateway enable on this subnet.

When app service send a request to internet it’s ok public ip of nat gateway is used
but when app service call request to sql virtual machine in same virtual network than subnet dedicated for app service public ip of nat gateway is used instead of private ip of subnet of app service

can i someone help me please thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hope this might help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-gateway/nat-gateway-resource